# Why do I need these proguard rules for Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I just upgraded to latest google play services (11.6.0). When I build with proguard I now get these warnings:

```
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza: can't find referenced method 'android.app.NotificationChannel getNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza: can't find referenced method 'void createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setChannelId(java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbga: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp()' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgb: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp(java.lang.String)' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
```

Why am I seeing this? I thought GMS handled it's own Proguard rules. From the documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> Note: ProGuard directives are included in the Play services client
>   libraries to preserve the required classes. The Android Plugin for
>   Gradle automatically appends ProGuard configuration files in an AAR
>   (Android ARchive) package and appends that package to your ProGuard
>   configuration. During project creation, Android Studio automatically
>   creates the ProGuard configuration files and build.gradle properties
>   for ProGuard use. To use ProGuard with Android Studio, you must enable
>   the ProGuard setting in your build.gradle buildTypes. For more
>   information, see the ProGuard guide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the [release notes for Google Play services 11.2.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_2017_-_version_1120):

> When you upgrade your app’s Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or later, your app’s build.gradle must also be updated to specify a compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O). This does not change the way your app runs.

Update your `compileSdkVersion` (note, you do not need to also update your `targetSdkVersion` - that can be done later) so that the referenced methods, which were added in API 26, can be found.

Comment: Perfect, this is the correct answer. If you're unable to update the target SDK version (you should always target the latest, but if you absolutely have to for whatever reason), then [11.0.4](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_2017_-_version_110) is the highest which can be targeted with API 25, so you may use that.